# Is it possible to have a contextual zoom node with a sub flow layout, in react-flow?

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

To create a [contextual zoom](https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/interaction/contextual-zoom/) node, one must create a custom nodeStyle.

I am looking to create a contextual zoom node, that displays a sub-flow inside of the zoomed state of of this node.  Are there any known ways to solve this?

The only solutions I could think of are to:

1. Create another react-flow instance and render it inside of the nodes. (this solution is problematic because we won't have reference to the parent node)
2. I've also tried rendering the child nodes as static children node styles. (this is problematic because it strips away the interactive nature of [sub-flows](https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/layout/sub-flows/)